# How do I use JSON from a JSON file in a separate JS file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

How do I use values from a JSON file I made in a different JS file?

```
const billingInfo = import("billing.json");

var addressInfo = {
  'first_name': first_name, //output: not defined
  'last_name': last_name //output: not defined
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = require('./billing.json');
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: It depends if content is being exported

Comment: how do I export from a JSON file, cuz I'd like to do that

Comment: I've updated my answer as require seems to work better.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Import file:

```
fetch('billing.json').then(response => response.json()) .then(obj => console.log(obj))
```

Comment: how will this let me access values from the file?

Comment: Content of file is being returned as 

.then(obj => console.log(obj)

Comment: u cant use fetch for a local file

Comment: Use u relative path ./billing.json

Comment: TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported
`fetch('./testBilling.json').then(response => response.json()) .then(obj => console.log(obj))`